# HTML DOM Parser : how to get the url only from one domain?

Tags: php

```
function get_link_and_anchor($url_awal) {
$html = file_get_html($url_awal);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $url_dari_konten = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $urltext = $anchor->nodeValue;

    $url_hasil = url_to_absolute(@$url_awal, @$url_dari_konten);

    echo $urltext . " : " . $url_hasil . "<br/>";
}
```

}

**Result :**
Twitter : ht*ps://twitter.com/batagrams 
Google + : ht*ps://plus.google.com/115711571208014927563 
Home : ht*p://batagrams.com/
About : ht*p://batagrams.com/about
Training : ht*p://batagrams.com/training
News : ht*p://batagrams.com/news

**i wanna get only :**
Home : ht*p://batagrams.com/
About : ht*p://batagrams.com/about
Training : ht*p://batagrams.com/training
News : ht*p://batagrams.com/news

i'm use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and url_to_absolute

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === "myhost.com"
```

to filter the URLs you've found.

Comment: it's working, thankyou  Frist Van Campen.. (y)

  if (parse_url($url_hasil, PHP_URL_HOST) === $host) {

            echo $urltext . " : " . $url_hasil . "<br/>";
        }